ddrescue second run, running time: n/a
I am running ddrescue to rescue a Windows 10 drive to a new SSD from a gparted media drive. I ran it successfully the first time with:
sudo ddrescue -f -d -n /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /path/to/map.log.
I wanted to run it a second time but in reverse to scrape as much data as possible from some bad sectors.
sudo ddrescue -f -d -n -R /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /path/to/map.log.
But the process finishes immediately
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:         0 GB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:         0 GB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:       0 B/s
non-tried:         0 kB,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:       0 B/s
  rescued:    109604 GB,   bad areas:        0,        run time:          0s
pct rescued:   100.00%, read errors:         0,  remaining time:         n/a
                                time since last successful read:         n/a
Finished

Is there a way to make it run a second time or should I save the data to an image, run the second and third time with scrape, and then write the image to the new SSD with rsync?

There is definetly something to scrape as the disk has  102 Gb of data and only 98 Gb were copied.

The weird part is rescued: 109604 GB, this is 109 TB.

That is the amount of data ddrescue apparently recovered. The disk was indeed damaged as it would desconnect using gparted to copy the partitions, and required to powercycle the device.
But it is wierd that ddrescue would output 100% rescued and not allow a second run. the recovered partition was not usable but files could be recovered.
